# Can you add Workspace Security to an existing Magnolia workspace?

Tags: postgresql, magnolia

We have a Magnolia CMS 5.5 Setup with an PostgreSQLPersistence Manager. I was investigating a case where our security config did not work as expected. I found out that our workspace/repository config was missing these three lines:

```
<WorkspaceSecurity>
  <AccessControlProvider class="info.magnolia.cms.core.MagnoliaAccessProvider" />
</WorkspaceSecurity>
```

Is there there a way to recreate the existing workspaces including this config or is there only the possibility to export and reimport the data into a fresh install (which is in our case going to take very long)?

Edit:
It worked for my local system, when i used the following repo-conf.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Repository PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 1.5//EN"
 "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-1.5.dtd">
<Repository>
  <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
    <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository" />
  </FileSystem>
  <Security appName="magnolia">
    <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager"/>
    <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager">
    </AccessManager>
    <!-- login module defined here is used by the repo to authenticate every request. not by the webapp to authenticate user against the webapp context (this one has to be passed before thing here gets invoked -->
    <LoginModule class="info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JackrabbitAuthenticationModule">
    </LoginModule>
  </Security>
  <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore">
    <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/datastore"/>
    <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024"/>
  </DataStore>
  <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default" />
  <Workspace name="default">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
      <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/default" />
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager">
      <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx" />
      <param name="databaseType" value="postgresql" /><!-- warning, this is not the schema name, it's the db type -->
      <param name="user" value="xxxxx" />
      <param name="password" value="xxxxxx" />
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_" />
      <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
    </PersistenceManager>
    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
      <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index" />
      <param name="useCompoundFile" value="true" />
      <param name="minMergeDocs" value="100" />
      <param name="volatileIdleTime" value="3" />
      <param name="maxMergeDocs" value="100000" />
      <param name="mergeFactor" value="10" />
      <param name="maxFieldLength" value="10000" />
      <param name="bufferSize" value="10" />
      <param name="cacheSize" value="1000" />
      <param name="forceConsistencyCheck" value="false" />
      <param name="autoRepair" value="true" />
      <param name="analyzer" value="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer" />
      <param name="queryClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryImpl" />
      <param name="respectDocumentOrder" value="true" />
      <param name="resultFetchSize" value="2147483647" />
      <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="3" />
      <param name="extractorTimeout" value="100" />
      <param name="extractorBackLogSize" value="100" />
      <!-- needed to highlight the searched term -->
      <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
      <!-- custom provider for getting an HTML excerpt in a query result with rep:excerpt() -->
      <param name="excerptProviderClass" value="info.magnolia.jackrabbit.lucene.SearchHTMLExcerpt"/>
    </SearchIndex>
    <WorkspaceSecurity>
      <AccessControlProvider class="info.magnolia.cms.core.MagnoliaAccessProvider" />
    </WorkspaceSecurity>
  </Workspace>
  <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
      <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/workspaces/version" />
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager">
      <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxx" />
      <param name="schema" value="postgresql" /><!-- warning, this is not the schema name, it's the db type -->
      <param name="user" value="xxxxxxxx" />
      <param name="password" value="xxxxxxxx" />
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_" />
      <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
    </PersistenceManager>
  </Versioning>
</Repository>
```

Here removing/adding the WorkspaceSecurity works.
But on the relevant system we have another config where adding the WorkspaceSecurity does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Repository PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 1.5//EN"
 "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-1.5.dtd">
<Repository>
  <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
    <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository" />
  </FileSystem>
  <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
    <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleAccessManager"></AccessManager>
    <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleLoginModule">
      <param name="yyyyyyy" value="yyyyyyy" />
    </LoginModule>
  </Security>
  <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore">
    <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/datastore"/>
    <param name="minRecordLength" value="1024"/>
  </DataStore>
  <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default" />
  <Workspace name="default">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
      <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/default" />
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager">
      <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxx" />
      <param name="schema" value="postgresql" /><!-- warning, this is not the schema name, it's the db type -->
      <param name="user" value="xxxxxxxx" />
      <param name="password" value="xxxxxxxx" />
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_" />
      <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
    </PersistenceManager>
    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
      <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index" />
      <param name="useCompoundFile" value="true" />
      <param name="minMergeDocs" value="100" />
      <param name="volatileIdleTime" value="3" />
      <param name="maxMergeDocs" value="100000" />
      <param name="mergeFactor" value="10" />
      <param name="maxFieldLength" value="10000" />
      <param name="autoRepair" value="true" />
      <param name="analyzer" value="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer" />
      <param name="queryClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryImpl" />
      <param name="respectDocumentOrder" value="true" />
      <param name="resultFetchSize" value="2147483647" />
      <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="3" />
      <param name="extractorTimeout" value="100" />
      <param name="extractorBackLogSize" value="100" />
      <!-- needed to highlight the searched term -->
      <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
      <!-- custom provider for getting an HTML excerpt in a query result with rep:excerpt() -->
      <param name="excerptProviderClass" value="info.magnolia.jackrabbit.lucene.SearchHTMLExcerpt"/>
    </SearchIndex>
  </Workspace>
  <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
      <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/workspaces/version" />
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager">
      <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxxxx" />
      <param name="schema" value="postgresql" /><!-- warning, this is not the schema name, it's the db type -->
      <param name="user" value="xxxxx" />
      <param name="password" value="xxxxxxx" />
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_" />
      <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
    </PersistenceManager>
  </Versioning>
</Repository>
```

Using the first config on the relevant system leads to lots of errors in the log. Do you have an idea how to solve this?
Thanks, Reencode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy existing workspaces using Workspace API but this doesn't help you. You can export the rootNode and import it to a fresh install which as you mentioned will take a lot of time as well. However, I'm a bit puzzled with accessControlProvider class configuration because it should be just working fine when one adds it to the configuration and restarts the instance. This is because the permission checks are done in the runtime and shouldn't affect it in a way that changing class has no effect whatsoever. I'd suggest checking this first and if still for some reason things don't work, then I'd check RepositoryCopier API and maybe there is a way to set that class while calling

```
 RepositoryCopier.copy();
```

Cheers,

Comment: Indeed, just add missing lines and restart. The permissions themselves are stored outside of workspace so you needthe class just to perform actual checks. Workspace content is not affected at all.

Comment: Unfortunately answer stays the same.

Comment: Okay I did it :) The trick was to first add the workspace security directly to the workspaces.xml (${magnolia.home}/repositories/magnolia/workspaces/<workspace_N>/workspace.xml) And also change the complete <security>..</security> part in our repo conf. Now acls are working as expected. Thanks again for your help. RC